# unknown error: missing or invalid arg value in Protractor

Tags: protractor

With the latest version of Protractor (4.0.9), chromedriver (2.24), chrome(54.0).
 while we perform **browser.navigate().back()**, we could observe the below error.

> **Failed:** unknown error: missing or invalid arg value   (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431
>   (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 5.36 seconds
>   Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30
>   17:37:03' System info: host: 'HW0705', ip: '172.16.28.83', os.name:
>   'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_60' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.24.417431
>   (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),
>   userDataDir=C:\Users\IN02137\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7732_2284},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false,
>   version=54.0.2840.71, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   aafe05d9edb4edf638aa556a5ca6b2cb [14:50:28] E/launcher - Error
>   communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

We are unable to perform any key operations with the new version, Can someone help us.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in Chromedriver 2.24 you need to update to the latest 2.25 from the command line as follows

> webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.25

And start the webdriver-manager as follows

> webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome 2.25

The latest version of webdriver-manager which ships with protractor 4.0.9 still runs 2.24 as the default.

(edit): For those running chimp also running into this showstopper, you'll want to update your version in your chimp/bin/default.js to 2.25 as the 0.41.2 build. defaults 2.24

This was an annoying bug.

Comment: `webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome 2.25` was the part that I was missing out. Thank you!

Comment: `webdriver-manager update` helped me to solve _WebDriverError: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'_